# How to render custom Shipping Address renderer

Tags: magento2, checkout

How to override this default shipping address renderer 
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\shipping-address\address-renderer\default.js

Magento have Documentation on this but some points are not clear
Source: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_address.html

The address_type you need to specify in the layout, is the value you set in the JS model of your custom address type.

How to create JS model and specify address_type ?